# Is there a way to mix ninja forms with WP-reCAPTCHA plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, captcha

I am trying to implement wordpress recaptcha in a ninja form but unfortunately it is not officially supported. I tried the shortcode in a custom field but this also didn't work. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: please post code you have tried so far

Comment: So far i have enabled the WP-reCAPTCHA plugin and i used the "recaptcha_form" shortcode in a text field inside a ninja form.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggeling with the same problem and finally found myself writing my own recaptcha plugin:
https://github.com/mcguffin/wp-recaptcha-integration
regards, j.